# Почему не срабатывает команда awk?

Tags: linux, ssh

Нужно выцепить процент использования диска: взять значение из 5 столбца 2 строки

Ввожу такую команду:

```
ssh <тут имя хоста> "df -h | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/%//'"
```

В конечном итоге выводит полностью всю 2 строку

Comment: Ну если вы запускаете команду из под линукса, то вот это будет работать -  `ssh localhost 'df -h' | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $5}'| sed 's/%//'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

выводится строка полностью потому, что программа *awk* получает в виде аргумента не `{print $5}`, а `{print }`.

производит эту замену ваша локальная оболочка ввиду того, что аргумент программе *ssh* заключён в двойные кавычки. а в вашей локальной оболочке переменная `$5` — пуста.

чтобы не менять один вид кавычек на другой, можно просто добавить символ `\` перед символом `$`:

```
... {print \$5} ...
```