# awk ничего не выводит

Tags: bash, awk

Всем доброго дня!
Есть скрипт который построчно генерирует данные в консоль. Хочу на лету парсить данные и выделять только то что нужно. Если делаю так `start.sh > test.txt
cat test.txt | grep -o "blabla" | awk "{ print $0}"`, то все работает как планировалось - показывает blabla, но вот так: `start.sh | grep -o "blabla" | awk "{ print $0}"` ничего не показывает, хотя после grep вывод есть, теряется в awk. Почему?

Comment: А что внутри start.sh происходит?

Comment: запуск java скрипта, который генерирует построчные данные

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> ... | awk "{print $0}"
> ```

если это используется в интерактивном сеансе оболочки, то ничего напечатано и не будет. точнее, будет напечатана пустая строка.

ведь благодаря двойным кавычкам вы «разрешаете» оболочке произвести подстановки внутри строки. и вместо `$0` оболочка подставит пустую строку. так как данная переменная в интерактивном сеансе не определена.

в итоге выполняется такая конструкция:

```
... | awk "{print }"
```

---

«быстрофикс» — используйте одинарные кавычки вокруг программы, передаваемой аргументом интерпретатору *awk*:

```
... | awk '{print $0}'
```

тогда оболочка не будет пытаться произвести подстановок.

---

практически идентичный вопрос: [Почему не срабатывает команда awk?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/867451/178576)

Comment: Кажется, я ждал ответа на этот вопрос больше, чем сам автор :)

Comment: К сожалению, у меня вариант замены кавычек не сработал

Comment: конечно, я не могу гарантировать, что у вас нет ещё каких-нибудь ошибок (в той же программе на java, например). я просто указал на одну единственную ошибку, вами озвученную.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так попробуйте:

```
while read -r line; do
    awk '{print $0}' < <(grep -o 'blablabla' <<<"$line") >> text.txt
done < <(start.sh)
```

Только не очень понятно зачем Вам `awk '{print $0}'` если у вас `grep -o` и так одно blablabla выведет. По сути `awk '{print $0}'` выдаст вам полный вывод `grep -o`

Comment: Это для примера, так как в awk будут различные условия

Comment: Впринципе если мой вариант не помог, хотелось бы увидет выво grep -o хотя бы приближенный к оригиналу

Comment: При запуске цикла получаю redirection unexpected. grep -o выдает "/dev/keyboard"

Comment: Писал с телефона, везде получились не правильные кавычки. Если копипастили код, попробуйте сейчас повторить. Кавычки поправил